# Can't access phpmyadmin and local localhost:8000 with two errors for each of them

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, mysql, php

Recently reinstalled Ubuntu 21.04 on my computer and installed php8 and Nginx.
I run the server for Laravel and when I go to localhost:8000 I got this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = 
k8TiDjzbt96oJgAhUkwhOzJO0dYUcctBdLCLuvTK limit 1) 
http://localhost:8000/
```

I think this error comes from PDO.

and when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin I got this error:

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

When I type `php -m` in terminal:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
igbinary
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

When I search pdo in php.ini file:

```
[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict

[Pdo_mysql]
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll    
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll    
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll  
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll    
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

my Xampp version is 8.0.12

I also use PostgreSQL for my Django projects.